# imshow() dispalys nothing for int16 array in Octave

Tags: octave

I am working on Octave with a brain MRI dataset.

The data is in the form of hundreds of .mat fils.
I load the data file using: `x = load("filename.mat")` and the images are stored in the form of an array from 0 to 256.

Then when I try to `imshow(x.image)` a window pops up with 512 x 512 graph but is completely black.
It also throws a warning saying: `unsupported type for cdata (= int16 matrix).  Valid types are uint8, uint16, double, single, and bool.`

I have also tried casting the image array using: `imshow(cast(x, "double"))` and all the other data types mentioned above, but the result is almost the same.

Help me out here.

Comment: I have no problem to plot a `int16 matrix` with Octave 5.2. What is the output of `typeinfo(x.image)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`limits`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Displaying-Images.html) parameter of `imshow`. The image is appearing black because it only contains values in the range [0,256], while `int16` contains values up to 32767.

You can set the limits manually:

```matlab
imshow(x.image, [0, 256])
```

Or use

```matlab
imshow(x.image, [])
```

For automatic limit detection.

---

Note: on Octave, this will only work with supported types. Since your image doesn't contain negative values, you can convert the image to `uint16`, which will fit your values. Or you can use double, for a more general approach:

```matlab
imshow(uint16(x.image), [])
imshow(double(x.image), [])
```

In your case, if you don't mind the pixels with value 256 being saturated to 255, you can convert the image to `uint8`:

```matlab
imshow(uint8(x.image))
```